# Highchart's Highstock date input & async loading

Tags: highcharts

When using the async function to load the graph, it does not seem to be possible to use the date input filter with a **To** date in the past.

For example, take this example that is an edited version of the *Highstock - 1.7 million points with async loading* demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/Zm2Y5/1/

If you choose 2009 in the date input and hit enter it works. But if you then proceed to change it to 2008 and hit enter, the date will jump back to 2009 without reloading.

```
        rangeSelector : {
            buttons: [{
                type: 'hour',
                count: 1,
                text: '1h'
            }, {
                type: 'day',
                count: 1,
                text: '1d'
            }, {
                type: 'month',
                count: 1,
                text: '1m'
            }, {
                type: 'year',
                count: 1,
                text: '1y'
            }, {
                type: 'all',
                text: 'All'
            }],
            inputEnabled: true, 
            selected : 3
        },
```

Is this functionality not supported? If so, is there some way to get and update the inputted date input and dynamically zoom into that date?

Comment: It looks like a problem wiht our script which doesn't return data, but when you combine with your own data it will work.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with my graph actually. What do you mean by it doesn't return data? Because my `afterSetExtreme()` function does the same as yours.

Comment: I mean that URL which is used by getJSON doesn't work.